# tangent distance between two handwritten digits

Tags: tangent-spaces

Suppose we have two handwritten images "3"[MNIST three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUHfh.png) and "6"[MNIST six](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBfzu.png). The task is to compute the tangent distance between the two. An explanation at undergraduate level is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the topic so far? Do you know the definition of tangent distance?

Comment: Here is something about the topic : https://cedar.buffalo.edu/~srihari/CSE555/Chap4.Metrics-TangentDistance.pdf

Comment: great slides. thank you.  Suppose, we consider only rotation. Then the tangent vector $TV$ correspondes to the difference between the image $x'$ (as colomn vector) rotated $\alpha$ degrees around the center and the unrotated image (also as column vector) i.e., \begin{equation} \mathrm{\boldsymbol{TV}} = \mathcal{F}(\boldsymbol{x}^\prime; \alpha) - \boldsymbol{x}' \end{equation} (see slide 38). Is this correct? Do I have to compute the tangent vector for any rotation angle $\alpha$ ?